# Does difficulty matter for unlocking new ships?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I unlock all the other ships in the hangar?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83359/how-do-i-unlock-all-the-other-ships-in-the-hangar)

Do you have to be on normal mode to unlock ships? If no does normal have any impact on the chance you have of getting quest for certain ships? So far on easy i have found no quests, and on normal i found the crystal quest

Answer (score 6):

Nope, you can unlock ships on Easy just the same as Normal.  There is no requirement to play at a higher difficulty.  Once unlocked, you can play with those ships on either difficulty.

The events that unlock ships are randomized, so it's hard to say if they're any less likely on Easy than on Normal.  However, in my personal experience I've seen no difference.

Comment: This has been my experience  as well.