# Crystal Ship in FTL

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When trying to get the damaged stasis pod, does the map show a distress signal, or nothing?

Also, can I get the stasis pod on the first sector? What type of sector is the first sector even?

All of this is assuming I don't have the long range scanner, because I can't really get it early on.

Thanks! ☺

Comment: Related: [How do I unlock all the ships in the hangar?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83359/how-do-i-unlock-all-the-other-ships-in-the-hangar)

Answer (score 4):

It'll be a normal distress signal. You'll then need to [complete additional steps](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Achievements/Ancestry). The [event](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Dense_Asteroid_Field_Distress_Call) does not occur in Civilian sectors like the first sector. I've unlocked the Crystal Cruiser, the methods linked definitely work.